# Terminology for photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

I'm currently writing a report on the photoelectric effect and I can't figure out how to say what I want to say. Essentially, I want to describe it as a "binary system" or "on/off system" (in that there is no observed activity until the incident energy exceeds the work function). What's the best, most scientific way to phrase this?

Thanks!

Comment: words such as 'discrete' and 'threshold' may help

Comment: Also cutoff and perhaps quantized